# Nested setInterval and setTimeout

Tags: javascript, settimeout, setinterval, clearinterval

I have something like this:

```
var activityTextToggleTimerTwo = setInterval(function() {
    active_users_text.toggleClass("active inactive bounce bounceOutUp")
    var activityTextToggleTimerThree = setTimeout(function() {
        active_users_text.toggleClass("active inactive bounce bounceOutUp");
    }, 5000);
}, 25000);
```

I try to clear the timeout/interval like so:

```
clearInterval( activityTextToggleTimerTwo );
clearTimeout( activityTextToggleTimerThree );
```

I get an exception:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: activityTextToggleTimerThree is not defined
```

Why? Also i think the activityTextToggleTimerThree does not get cleared..

Thanks

Comment: You can't clear `activityTextToggleTimerThree` because it's insde a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable is out of scope, because it's defined inside the callback to `setInterval`. You have to move it to the outer scope, but you may still have a problem: every time the `setInterval` callback is executed, you'll be replacing the timer handler in that variable, so you'll only be able to clear the latest `setTimeout` timer.

Comment: thanks for pointing that i will be only clearing the "latest" timer... So how do i go about this? Thanks

Comment: If you need to clear multiple timers, you can keep their handlers in an array.

Answer (score 0):

Put the `.clearInterval()` method inside the `.setInterval()` anonymous function, like:

```
// assuming you have active_users_text defined
var rotations = 0;
var activityTextToggleTimerTwo = setInterval(function(){
  active_users_text.toggleClass('active inactive bounce bounceOutUp');
  // change 1 if you want
  if(rotations < 1){
    var activityTextToggleTimerThree = setTimeout(function(){
      active_users_text.toggleClass('active inactive bounce bounceOutUp');
    }, 5000);
  }
  // change 75000 if you want
  if(rotations++ == 75000){
    clearInterval(activityTextToggleTimerTwo);
  }
}, 25000);
```

`setTimeout()` won't need to be cleared using this methodology.